# Problema com APK

Tags: android

Estou com um problema com o arquivo APK gerado pelo android studio, quando eu instalo o app via AVD Manager o App funciona normalmente, porem se eu pegar o apk de debug e instalar no mesmo dispositivo, ao tentar abrir o App ele fecha automátiamente. Alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: abre o logcat no Android Studio com o celular plugado e vê qual o erro apareceu

Comment: se e o apk de debug voce consegue o pegar o erro no android studio

Comment: Deu um erro,  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout. Resolvi recriando o Layout. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Android Studio tem uma função de gerar o arquivo apk para ser instalador e tem outra função para compilar e executar, são duas rotinas separadas mas as duas geram um apk, e a de compilar gera um apk incompleto.

Vá em Build\Builds APK, essa rotina sim gera o instalador. As Rotinas Run, Make, Debug geram os apk incompleto, uma versão para ser executada direto no emulador ou do cabo USB.

Comment: Oi eu já tinha testado dessa forma acabei por seguir a orientação do Paulo e do Neuber, deu o erro:  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout. Resolvi refazendo o Layout